# Applying offset for Matrix4 in flutter for Interactive Viewer

Tags: flutter

Am trying to build zoom in zoom out button for InteractiveViewer Widget using this list and transformation controller

```
List<Matrix4> zoom = [
  Matrix4(  1,0,0,0,
              0,1,0,0,
              0,0,1,0,
             0 ,0,0,1,) ,
              Matrix4(  2,0,0,0,
              0,2,0,0,
              0,0,1,0,
              0,0,0,1,) ,
               Matrix4(  3,0,0,0,
              0,3,0,0,
              0,0,1,0,
              0,0,0,1,) ,

]  ;
                 TransformationController transformationcontroller = TransformationController () ;
```

and this is the Ui

```
  InteractiveViewer(
                              transformationController: transformationcontroller,
                               panEnabled: true, // Set it to false to prevent panning. 
                            
           
              minScale: 1,
              maxScale: 5, 
                              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                height: 315.0,
                                width: 315.0,
                                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                imageUrl: "${API.api}/images/products/$currentvalue",
                                placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                    const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),
                              ),
                            ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [InkWell(
                                    onTap: () {
                                   
                                      if((index >= 0)&&(index < zoom.length -1)) {
                                        index ++ ;
                                    
                                        setState(() {
                transformationcontroller.value = zoom[index] ; 
              
                });
                                      }
                                    },
                                    child: Icon(Icons.zoom_in,size: 40.0,color: AppColor.buttonfill,)),InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                          if((index >= 1)&&(index < zoom.length )) {
                                            index -- ;
                                          
                                            setState(() {
                transformationcontroller.value = zoom[index];
                });
                                          }
 
                                      },
                                      child: Icon(Icons.zoom_out,size: 40.0,color: AppColor.buttonfill,))],),
```

the scaling is working but it always offset to the top left of the image
I want it to stay at center where ever he start zooming

I tried giving x ,y values to the matrixes but getting the image disapear as following

```
List<Matrix4> zoom = [
  Matrix4(  1,0,0,0,
              0,1,0,0,
              0,0,1,0,
             0 ,0,0,1,) ,
              Matrix4(  2,0,0,100,
              0,2,0,100,
              0,0,1,0,
              0,0,0,1,) ,
               Matrix4(  3,0,0,200,
              0,3,0,200,
              0,0,1,0,
              0,0,0,1,) ,

]  ;
```

I also tried
`transformationcontroller.toScene(Offset(dx, dy))`
with same result too ... hope some one can help
thank you all

Comment: can you please explain to me why putting 100 for x and y in the second matrix causing the image to disappear !!